# How can I access my Linux VM from the browser on my host machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have been looking forever and I can't find an answer that works for me. Please help.

Comment: This is a pretty low-effort question and it's hard to tell exactly what you're wanting to know. Based solely on your tags, it looks like you're running a VM on your machine using Virtualbox and you're hosting a website on said VM, and you're wondering how you can access that website from your host machine.  There could be a number of things wrong. The VM firewall could be preventing access, you could have the network configured wrong for the VM, etc. Please give some more info about what you have already tried so your question can be answered.

Comment: Your VM lies on a virtual network provided by your virtualization software. It has (should have) an IP on this virtual network. You can access your VM on that IP. You can also make bridging or routing between your real network and your virtual one, it depends on your virtualization software.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiles softwares that deploy a web server on your server that can then be access without client side installation via your favorite browser.

I have already used [ttyd](https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd), [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/) (its more a monitoring solution that can also provide a console access).

I also found the following : [webtty](https://github.com/maxmcd/webtty) and [guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/) (more like a web teamviewver)